# Web Scraping file path for CSV output

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to web scraping. This is my first attempt. I currently have a working script that creates my output but lands it in the same file as where my script is saved.
How do I add a file path to where I want my csv to be saved?
I will be running it from linux.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/tax-policy/foreign-account-tax-compliance-act'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[0]
print(df)
df.to_csv('FATCA_Data.csv', index = None, header = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just prepend the full path before the file name.

```
df.to_csv('\home\folder1\folder2\FATCA_Data.csv', index = None, header = True)
```

Comment: That seems to be trying to name the file the filepath but still in the same folder

Comment: well maybe try it before commenting that ;)

Comment: are you sure you indicated a path to a directory that existed ?

Comment: Yeah, i'm trying to save it in `F:\FATCA Scrape\Fatca_data.csv` but it is saving in same folder as script as FFATCA~1.csv

Comment: you can try to check with ```pwd``` in the terminal to see if the path is correct, or use relative paths like for example: ```../folder1/etc... ``` to save it to a directory relkative to the one it is saved at the moment.